# Wrong value coming from Doctrine 2 'getClassMetadata()->getIdentifier()', how or why?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following Entity as part of a Symfony 3.2.6 project in Doctrine 2:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
use QuoteBundle\Model\SourceTrait;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="quote")
 */
class Quote
{
    use SourceTrait;
    use TimestampableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer",unique=true,nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $quoteId;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getQuoteId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->quoteId;
    }
}
```

In another class *dynamically* I need to get the identifier of the entities (I wrote just an example of the entities - the one above - but this applies to all of the entities I have all over the application) so the best way I found to achieve this was using `getClassMetaData()` method from Doctrine.

This is the *dynamic* code into the class:

```
$modelMetaData = $em->getClassMetadata($bundleName.':'.$modelName);
```

Which gets translated for example in:

```
$modelMetaData = $em->getClassMetadata('QuoteBundle:Quote');
```

From there I should have all the data related to the entity.

One of the problem is we're two developers and we're having different results regarding `getClassMetaData()`.

I am running a stack in Docker using Docker Compose which is exactly the same and this mean: same PHP version (7.1.2), same Apache version, same MySQL version (this one is in a common server outside the stack) and same Symfony libraries. I have checked, double checked and triple checked and can do it again if it's necessary.

For the examples from now on I'll call myself Dev1 and the second developer will be Dev2.

Dev1 code:

```
$id = $em->getClassMetadata('QuoteBundle:Quote')->getIdentifier()[0];
dump($id);

quote_id
```

Dev2 code:

```
$id = $em->getClassMetadata('QuoteBundle:Quote')->getIdentifier()[0];
dump($id);

quoteId
```

As you can see the ID obtained is different which is making the code to fails on Dev2 environment and I don't know what else to look since everything seems to be fine for me.

The question is: should `getIdentifier()` return `quote_id` (the column name) or `quoteId` (the mapped name)??

As an addition [here](https://gist.github.com/reypm/68e15f36457d1d7d558d9aafd308475f) is an example of `dump($modelMetaData)` for Dev1 and [here](https://gist.github.com/reypm/c4cb9d07ce9ec52258776b3deac8e1af) the same example for Dev2.

Comment: I think it should return `quoteId`. BTW, have you tried without the `[0]` part? Maybe it returns both, not always in the same order?

Comment: Just for kicks try getSingleIdentifierFieldName() and getSingleIdentifierColumnName() http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.ClassMetadataInfo.html#1846-1852 And of course do the ever popular cache clearing stuff.